# Let the code work after powerpoint exits the presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Zoomed Chart with Powerpoint VBA. After zooming in on the graphic, I need code to return to the previous one.

sample:1

Below is the version before running the presentation:

[image]

sample:2

After running the presentation, when I click on the Period Chart, it zooms with the help of code:

[image]

Sample:3
When you leave the presentation, it comes to its final form.

[image]

Sample:4
Let me return to the first automatic initial state after closing the presentation I want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxJWb.jpg)

Powerpoint file:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: Thank you John Korchok.

Comment: Normally, you would edit your original question and post the code there. 

Rather than using VBA to zoom the chart, why not use an animation to get the same visual effect? That automatically returns the charts to their original state.

Comment: I have to use VBA because it is in my different works. I would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Yakınlaştır_1()
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Width > 25 * 28.34646 Then

ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Top = 11.4 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Left = 2.47 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Height = 6.12 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Width = 12.71 * 28.34646


Else

ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Top = 1.86 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Left = 1.15 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Height = 15.33 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").Width = 31.57 * 28.34646


ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("hehe").ZOrder msoBringToFront
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("dnm").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If

End Sub

Sub Yakınlaştır_2()
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Width > 25 * 28.34646 Then

ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Top = 11.4 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Left = 19.9 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Height = 6.19 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Width = 11.64 * 28.34646

Else

ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Top = 1.32 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Left = 1.13 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Height = 16.31 * 28.34646
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").Width = 30.7 * 28.34646


ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("hehe").ZOrder msoBringToFront
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("İl").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If

End Sub
```